# Is there a SOAP gem that doesn't depend on nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, handsoap

I have tried the savon gem and it works fine.

Unfortunately, I cannot use it for the actual application as we cannot use Nokogiri. I looked at soap4r and it seems to be very old. I also looked at handsoap and have yet to fully test it for my service.

Could someone please share any other gem to consume a SOAP web service using Ruby, without relying on Nokogiri?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help but would you mind to explain why you can't use Nokogiri?

Comment: We need to embed the application on a mobile device and Nokigiri seems to be having several dependench gems with it. We are using Rhomobile. If we have thin SOAP client, that would make our life easier

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck with one of the more actively maintained [soap4r](https://github.com/felipec/soap4r) forks.